# Am I really mutating the list?

Tags: python, list, mutation

Say i'm given a list

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4]
removed_item = lst1.pop()
lst1.append(removed_item)
```

I've changed the values for a temporary time, however I've reverted everything back to normal after the run. Is this considered mutating the list?

Comment: If you only want to modify the value of the last element, you can access it by `lst1[-1]`.

Comment: Yes you are. If there were other threads, this would cause a data race.

Comment: Ok cool, thnaks

Comment: Are you asking if Python has a way of optimizing these kinds of calls?

Comment: @AustinA No, I was just unsure if I really understood the definition of mutation in python.

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting question: what about `lst1.append(lst1.pop())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you do, because you removed an item (mutating the list) and then re-append it (mutating the list... again).

Answer (score 0):

Lists are mutable and strings are not. Run this code and you will get the answer

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4]
print(id(lst1))
removed_item = lst1.pop()
print(id(lst1))
lst1.append(removed_item)
print(id(lst1))

str1 = "a string"
print(id(str1))
removed_item = str1[-1]
str1 = str1[:-1]
print(id(str1))
str1 += removed_item
print(id(str1))
```